# How to adjust the videobrush aspect ratio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to place a videobrush in my application, although I've noticed that in portrait mode the aspect ratio is different than in landscape mode. How would I adjust this so that the videorbush remains in its default aspect ratio regardless of the rotation of the phone?

MainPage.xaml

```
<Rectangle x:Name="videoRectangle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VideoBrush  x:Name="viewfinderBrush">
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <!--<CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderBrushTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Rotation="90" />-->
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderBrushTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"  />
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
..do adjustments in code behind?
```

To note, I have set `SupportedOrientations="Portrait"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use set the [Brush.RelativeTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.relativetransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to a [CompositeTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) according to the orientation of the device.

Check [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and search for "OnOrientationChanged" on the code to see what you'll need to do in your app.